# DOCX SetColumnWidth null reference exception table insert

Tags: c#, ms-word, nullreferenceexception, novacode-docx

Getting a null reference exception and a break on `t.SetColumnWidth(i, 0.83);`.
I want to insert a Table at a specified point and set the column widths.  What's wrong with my code, I'm using the DOCX API?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Novacode;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplicationSample
{
    class CreateDocument
    {
        public void CreateSampleDocument()
        {

            string fileName = @"C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\DocXExample.docx";

            var doc = DocX.Load(fileName);
            Table t = doc.AddTable(4, 4);

            t.Alignment = Alignment.center;          
            for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
            {
                t.SetColumnWidth(i, 0.83);
            }
            t.Rows[0].Cells[0].Paragraphs[0].Append("Daniel Taki");
            t.Rows[0].Cells[1].Paragraphs[0].Append("Mike Jones");

            foreach (var paragraph in doc.Paragraphs)
            {
                paragraph.FindAll("#TABLE#").ForEach(indexer => paragraph.InsertTableAfterSelf((t)));
            }

            doc.ReplaceText("#TABLE#", "");

            doc.Save();

            Process.Start("WINWORD.EXE", fileName);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Instead of using `SetColumnWidth` I tried to use nested for loops to iterate through each cell in the table and set the cell width individually. This ended up with the resulting table, which is not what I wanted.

```
  var numberOfRows = t.RowCount;
  var numberOfColumns = t.ColumnCount;


            for(int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; row++)
            {
                for(int col = 0; col < numberOfColumns; col++)
                {
                    t.Rows[row].Cells[col].Width = 0.86;
                }

            }
```

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23692439/how-can-i-control-table-column-width-in-word-documents-using-docx check this other wise consult with the `novacode-docx` documentation or do a google search on the following `novacode docx SetColumnWidth`

Comment: Yeah that's the one I was looking at he said he you have iterate through every cell in the table and change the width, but I couldn't find a property to change cell width, until just right now haha.  This may work, but why can't I set the column width with the method `SetColumnWidth`...shouldn't that work as well?

Comment: I am not sure in `navacode-docx` I use `OpenXml assembly and ClosedXml assembly` to create my docs

Comment: I have tried this on server different occassions and get the same errors. I am wondering if this is an issue with the docX package?